# react-admin saving a resource is sending parts of the wrong resource

Tags: react-admin

At this point I have a users resource and a roles resource.   I can edit a user fine, but when I go in and edit a role, it shows all the role fiels properly, but clicking Save and it's sending the wrong info to the backend.  It seems to be caching some data, because it's sending the last user id that I edited and some of the user fields, along with some of the role fields from my actual role model.

Not even sure how to explain this properly, but I can try and give some better examples of what I am seeing if it will help.

EDIT: Perhaps it is some form of local caching.  I went back to start debugging more and now it's sending everything properly.

EDIT #2: Definitely some sort of caching.  Now when I edit a user it is sending some of properties of the role that I last edited along with the user properties.

Comment: It looks like this bug, it is fixed but not released yet: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2037

Comment: Thanks, that certainly appears to be it.